# jQuery nth-child selector not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have JavaScript code here to detect a `#` in the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) and then add an active class to an element if detected. However, on the three cases with the nth-child selector, nothing is happening, and I am not sure why.

```
switch (window.location.hash) {
    case "#MAIN":
        $('#tab li a.nav:first').addClass('act').siblings().addClass('inact');
        break;
    case "#sg2":
        $('#tab li a.nav:nth-child(2)').addClass('act').siblings().addClass('inact');
        alert($('#tab li a.nav:nth-child(2)').className);
        break;
    case "#sg3":
        $('#tab li a.nav:nth-child(3)').addClass('act').siblings().addClass('inact');
        break;
    case "#zycsg":
        $('#tab li a.nav:nth-child(4)').addClass('act').siblings().addClass('inact');
        break;
    default:
        $('#tab li a.nav:first').addClass('act').siblings().addClass('inact');
}
```

How do I fix this problem?

#### HTML

```
<div id="tab">
    <ul>
        <li class="menuItem2"><a href="#MAIN" class="nav" onclick='window.history.pushState("", "", "/#MAIN");'>Home-1</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem2"><a href="#sg2" class="nav" onclick='window.history.pushState("", "", "/#sg2");'>HDCYG?</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem2"><a href="#sg3" class="nav" onclick='window.history.pushState("", "", "/#sg3");'>Home-3</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem2"><a href="#zycsg" class="nav" onclick='window.history.pushState("", "", "/#zycsg");' style="width:300px;">Zinteen youtube collection</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: we'd have to see the html, as there is nothing inherently wrong with your jQuery code, other than being a tad redundant. Also, your alert will always return undefined, since the jQuery selector always returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so in order to access the className property, you should use `alert($('#tab li a.nav:nth-child(2)')[0].className);`

Comment: @Neils I have added the html

Comment: Just a thought - could the issue be that after the `#MAIN` block executes all the links have the `inact` class, and that that hides the affect of applying the `act` class later?

Comment: @SteveWilkes when the link is clicked it gets the `act` class and all the others go `inact`

Comment: $('#tab li a.nav').removeClass('act').addClass('inact');
        $(this).addClass('act');

Comment: but you are never removing the act class, or the inact class in your code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, it should be either

```
$('#tab a.nav:nth-child(n)')
```

or

```
$('#tab li:nth-child(n) a.nav')
```

what you have now is looking for the nth child anchor of EACH li under #tab

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is already closed, but wouldn't it be easier to just use the href as your selector?

```
//get the hash
//find the anchor tag with the matching href and add the act class
//select all of the anchor tags with the nav class but not the nav and act class

var page = window.location.hash;
$('a.nav[href="'+page+'"]').addClass('act');
$('a.nav:not(.act)').addClass('inact');
```